# How to call the set procedure of an unique property type?

Tags: vb.net, properties, html-agility-pack

So i'm pretty new to property's and so far they have just DRIVING ME CRAZY :)...
From what i have understood, propertys are simply a function(get) that return the value, and a sub(set) that doing stuff...I looked at MSDN and iv'e seen that in order to "call" the set procedure you simply assign a value to the property and it start executing the procedure. My problem is that i cant simply assign a value to my property, e.g i have a HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument type property, and i cant figure out how to call it's set procedure.
Here is my code:

```
Private pFullHtml As HtmlDocument
Public Property FullHTML As HtmlDocument
    Get
        Return pFullHtml
    End Get
    Set(value As HtmlDocument)
        value = (vHtmlweb.Load(URL))
        value.OptionFixNestedTags = True
        pFullHtml = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I tried to do this in order to create an instance of FullHtml:    `FullHtml.New()` but it failed.
Any way, how can i put a value to a htmldocument type?...Unlike a simple integer property which i can simply do FullHtml=5...
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create instances of properties. Properties represent attributes of objects. They can be assigned or changed, but it would make no sense to create instances of them.

But you are able to create an instance of HtmlDocument and assign this instance to your property FullHTML, since FullHTML is just a name of some property.

Your code should look like:

```
ClassWithSomeProperty obj = new ClassWithSomeProperty ();
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
obj.FullHTML = document;
```